# How to insert/remove a new row(node) in a jXtreetable?

Tags: java, swing, jxtreetable

I'm trying to use `JXTreeTable` from the SwingLabs library `org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTreeTable`. I've a problem when I try to insert/remove a node into/from the table.

The fact is that I was expected to have a method that could fire the JXTreeTable when the data in its model change. But I didn't find anything like this. Could anyone tell me how to add or remove a node (parent or child) in a JXTreeTable?

PS: my model class extends `AbstractTreeTableModel`. I pass in its constructor a `LinkedList` and populate the JXTreeTable with the data contained in this List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AbstractTreeTableModel` has a protected member variable `modelSupport` of the type `TreeModelSupport`, which offers you a variety of such event methods:

- fireNewRoot()
- fireTreeStructureChanged(TreePath)
- firePathChanged(TreePath)
- fireChildChanged(TreePath, int, Object)
- fireChildrenChanged(TreePath, int[], Object[])
- fireChildAdded(TreePath, int, Object)
- fireChildRemoved(TreePath, int, Object)
- fireChildrenAdded(TreePath, int[], Object[])
- fireChildrenRemoved(TreePath, int[], Object[])
- addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener)
- removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener)